# TinyMCE Paragraph Text Only but with some buttons like bold, italics

Tags: textbox, tinymce

For my website I need the input passed from TinyMCE to be 1 specific font.
I need them to be able to insert links, make text bold, underlined or italics. They get to have 2 headers to chose from, Header 2 and Header 3 and paragraph.

Now the problem is, I can't make the editor paste as text. If I open word I can copy and paste text with font, lets say, Chiller and it shows up as chiller.

How can I make all copy/pasted text show as my desired font (paragraph format) while allowing some buttons to work such as bold..etc.

**What I currently have:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">                             
                            tinyMCE.init({
                            mode : "textareas",
                            theme : "advanced",
                            editor_selector : "body_content",
                            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,hr,strikethrough,formatselect,separator,undo,redo",
                            theme_advanced_buttons2: "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,link,unlink",
                            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
                            theme_advanced_blockformats: "p,h2,h3",
                            extended_valid_elements: "iframe[title|width|height|src]",
                            theme_advanced_fonts : "Arial=arial",
                            plugins : "wordcount",

                                    setup : function(ed){ 
                                        ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed){
                                            ///
                                            var r = 0;
                                            var y = tinyMCE.get('body_content').getContent();
                                            var n = "<?php echo $max;?>";                                               
                                            y = y.replace(/\s/g,' ');
                                            y = y.split(' ');
                                            for (i=0; i<y.length; i++) 
                                            {
                                                if (y[i].length > 0) r++;
                                            }
                                            var word_remain=n-r;
                                            if(word_remain<0)
                                                word_remain=0;
                                            jQuery('#body_word_remain').html(word_remain);
                                            var keypressed = null;

                                            if (window.event)
                                            {
                                                keypressed = window.event.keyCode; 
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                keypressed = ed.which; //NON-IE, Standard
                                            }
                                            if (r > n )
                                            {   
                                                var prescribed = "<?php _e('You have exceeded the prescribed ','ad')?>";
                                                prescribed += (r-n);
                                                prescribed += "<?php _e(' word(s)','ad');?>";
                                                jQuery('#prescribed').html(prescribed);                                                 
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                jQuery('#prescribed').html('');
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }                                       
                            });

                            </script>
```

**The example here works the way I want it to:**
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/

But I am not sure what they have used to achieve that effect. I am using a version 3.9.3 released on 2010-12-20 and I'd rather not update it if possible. But if I do need to update it to get my desired effect I will.

Thank you! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 3.9.3 is pretty outdaten (almost 2 years now) - i strongly suggest you update your version

Comment: Okay i'll give that a shot and report back to see if any of the settings I tried works on the newer version.

Comment: Just in case anyone sees this I solved the issue by updating.